# How do you filter & sort a RecyclerView that uses LiveData (without using a SearchView)

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-livedata

So I'm talking about a RecyclerView that displays a filtered/sorted list of items (the filter/sort criteria are preset and not up to the user, so no point in using SearchView) queried from a server/DB.

I thought about doing the sorting/filtering in the `setData` function of my custom adapter, like so:

```
fun setData(items: List<GenericObject>) {
    mValues.clear()
    mValues.addAll(items)
    mValues.filter { // filter conditions }
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

But this doesnt seem to work. What alternatives could I use, or whats the preferred way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the responsibility of the adapter to sort. It's the responsibility of whoever provides the data.

You could in fact use `ListAdapter` for your RecyclerView + `livedata.map { list -> list.filter {...}}`

Comment: Right, right. I solved the issue by using `MediatorLiveData` and using the filtered list as a source.

Comment: @string_loginUsername I have a similar use case.  Can you post your solution?